# How do I Integrate Two Menu Wordpress Plugins?

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins

I'm looking to have a logo with a drop down menu on my site, http://sheisbiddy.com/home/ I found a widget that changes a menu item to a photo (it's just called Menu Image) that worked beautifully. Then I added another widget (Max Mega Menu) to be able to add a dropdown menu and really customize it and make my life easier (less coding! Yay!). Problem is that it overrode the other widget and now there isn't a logo. I tried using the custom css feature to add it but it still isn't working (I asked about that in a different question here: http://bit.ly/1Pj1S3e). Is there anyway to get these plugins to play nice together? Or is there a better way to get both the logo and dropdown menu? I appreciate any advice you have! This is the last step until this site is ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

If its a plugin conflict, theres a good chance its because there is conflicting styles in each one, and one takes priority over the other. Finding those styles and commenting them out or deleting them might solve your issue.

In a worse situation, there could be a name conflict, but that seems doubtful here.

Comment: but commenting them out will be temporary until the plugin is updated no? @AidanBoyle

Comment: @CarolMcKay. Yes thats a good point. You might be better off overwriting the conflicting styles in your style.css file then. Theres likely only a few that would need to be rewrote.